# Drive Picker widget not working in Run as developer mode

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have an app that is running in the Run As Developer mode. However when I try to add a Drive Picker widget, I get the following error msg:

```
Access to Google Drive is unavailable in Run As Developer mode. Change this mode in App Settings.
```

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reference the documentation here [App Maker Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/input-widgets#drive-picker). It clearly states that your app has to be configured to run as user to use the Drive Picker widget.